# convert xpath to css in selenium webdriver not working properly?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Here i have tried to change from xpath to css as follow but it does not worked for me.

Xpath as

```
//*[@id='testPopups']/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/span
```

CSS as

```
css=div[id='testPopups'] >div:nth-child(5) >div:nth-child(1) >div:nth-child(2) >div:nth-child(7)
```

Its not working when i checked in FF as EVAL option.can anybody guide me how to change xpath to css for above.

Comment: har07,Is there any dynamic way to do the same ,if possible please tell me.

Comment: This is awesome :http://cssify.appspot.com/

Comment: Dynamic way to do what? To do conversion from XPath to CSS? You can read the logic from [source code](https://github.com/santiycr/cssify) of that cssify apps...

Comment: Why would you do this? The CSS path has no more semantic value than the original XPath. You should choose your selector carefully rather than using a generated value.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below:

```
css=div#testPopups >div:nth-child(5) >div:nth-child(1) >div:nth-child(2) >div:nth-child(7) > div>span
```